Hash Table and uniformly distribution
I'm trying to understand the relationship between input distributions and hash function performance in hash tables. In statistics, the theoretical probability of landing in a specific slot of a hash table is 1/, where m is the number of slots. However, if the hash function simply performs a modulo operation on the last digit of the numbers, and most numbers in my dataset end with the digit '6', it seems like it would skew the distribution towards certain slots.
In this scenario, does this mean that the probability of landing in a specific cell isn't uniformly 1/ due to the input pattern?
What is the difference in expected slot distribution between a general case to land on specific cell and a specific case (with given input) that has a pattern?
Thank you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In your scenario, the distribution would not be uniform and the probability of collisions would be substantially higher.  It would not be a good hash function.
